# Magento 2 Add Anchor link in Notice, Error or Success Message

Tags: magento2.3, phtml

The link shows exactly how it is typed instead of an actual link. What am I missing?

```
<div class="message notice">
    <div>
        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getNoResultText() ? $block->getNoResultText() : __('Your search returned no results. Use our <a href=\\>Part Finder</a> or <a href=\\contact>Contact</a> page if you cannot find what your looking for as we may have it or can order it in.')) ?>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($messages = $block->getNoteMessages()) : ?>
            <?php foreach ($messages as $message) : ?>
                <br /><?= /* @noEscape */ $message ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below code with your code and check.

```
<div class="message notice">
    <div>
        <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($block->getNoResultText()) ? $block->getNoResultText() : __('Your search returned no results. Use our <a href="%1">Part Finder</a> or <a href="%2">Contact</a> page if you cannot find what your looking for as we may have it or can order it in.',$this->getUrl('partfinder'), $this->getUrl('contact')) ?>
        <?= $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($messages = $block->getNoteMessages()):?>
            <?php foreach ($messages as $message):?>
                <br /><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $message ?>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.